# Is there such a thing as a “wonderful” number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, terminology

It am quite sure that I once heard on NPR that numbers of the form 
$$100p + q $$where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers less than $100$, are so-called wonderful numbers.  Did I, or they, get it wrong?  Google and Wolfram have no such references.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=j7ZIDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA258&lpg=PA258&dq=Find+the+sum+of+all+%E2%80%9Cwonderful%E2%80%9D+numbers+smaller+than+75&source=bl&ots=3VMT9h6696&sig=ACfU3U1UNtNQ9GvwCG5khzB4wSAbPSSqOw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxj7bko63nAhUCNKwKHZXzDJcQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Find%20the%20sum%20of%20all%20%E2%80%9Cwonderful%E2%80%9D%20numbers%20smaller%20than%2075&f=false this book calls $n$ a "wonderful number" if there are integers $a,b,k$ so that $3^n=a^k + b^k$....

Comment: Of course anyone can call anything anything...

Comment: Of course, but thank you for the reference.  It looks as though I am way off the mark, at least so far as the name goes.  I just thought that they might be interesting on some account, and I cannot for the life of me why such numbers came up in the discussion.   Thanks Again!

Comment: Well, truth is anybody can call anything "wonderful" numbers and that is just the one I find.  Probably someone else has come up with another.  I can't see numbers of the form $100p + q$ (Such as $3183$ or $1157$) are particularly *interesting* but there may be something you are forgetting or I am not getting.

Comment: @fleablood Isn't $57$ composite ?

Comment: "Isn't 57 composite"  Oh ... probably.... (or definitely).... $1159$ or $1361$ then.  Like I said.  I don't see much interesting in just them but maybe if they are also prime or not prime or if we define wonderful as a $2^k;k\ge 2$ digit number composed of two concatenated wonderful numbers (if $k > 2$... think this would be too limiting if the single digits had to be prime... or maybe it's still not interesting.)

Comment: 57 is the [Grothendieck prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/57_(number)#In_mathematics).